# Stored property with closure initializer does not allow local variable

Tags: swift, closures, xcode7, swift2

The following code works:

```
class Test {
    let api = "abc"
    let apiParam = {
       return ["api": api]
    }()
}
```

But when the constant api is moved into the apiParam property, I get error: "Cannot invoke closure of type {} -> _ with an argument list of ()"

```
class Test {
    let apiParam = {
      let api = "abc"
      return ["api": api]
    }()
 }
```

However, replacing the constant with actual value will rid of the error.

```
class Test {
    let apiParam = {
      return ["api": "abc"]
    }()
 }
```

Comment: Does it give the same error if you replace this line with: `return ["api": "abc"]`

Comment: @brimstone It does not.

Answer (score 1):

It's just Swift's cryptic way of telling you that you're not supplying it enough type information. Usually it's able to infer types pretty effectively, but can *sometimes* struggle, usually around closures. If you explicitly define the type of `apiParam`, the error will be dismissed.

```
class Test {
    let apiParam:[String:String] = {
        let api = "abc"
        return ["api": api]
    }()
}
```

Although note that your first example doesn't compile – you'll get an `instance member 'api' cannot be used on type 'Test'` error. This is because `self` will refer to the static class at that scope, rather than an instance – meaning you cannot access the `api` property.

You'd either need to make `apiParam` a lazy property (so that it's created when you first *access* it, meaning `self` will refer to the instance), or make `api` static, so it's available at class level.